# Unable to write to AWS ClouldWatch from docker container

Tags: .net-core, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch, serilog, docker-container

I'm running a .net core application in a windows container where it uses AWS SDK to connect to ClouldWatch. I have used Serilog.Sink.AWSCloudWatch for this integration.

CloudWatch integration works when I run it from my host machine however I'm getting below exception when I tried that from a windows docker container. As I am new to dockers, would you be able to help me to solve this issue.

```
 Error initializing log stream. No logs will be sent to AWS CloudWatch. Exception was System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No such host is known.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): No such host is known.
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Amazon.Runtime.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponseAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Serilog.Sinks.AwsCloudWatch.CloudWatchLogSink.CreateLogGroupAsync()
   at Serilog.Sinks.AwsCloudWatch.CloudWatchLogSink.EnsureInitializedAsync()
   at Serilog.Sinks.AwsCloudWatch.CloudWatchLogSink.EmitBatchAsync(IEnumerable`1 events).
```

Docker file,

```
ROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-nanoserver-1903 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanoserver-1903 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY *.sln .
COPY MyProject/*.csproj ./MyProject/
RUN dotnet restore

# copy full solution over
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build

FROM build AS release
WORKDIR "/src/MyProject"
RUN dotnet build "MyProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
WORKDIR "/src/MyProject"
RUN dotnet publish "MyProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /Users/ContainerUser/.aws
COPY credentials .

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.dll"]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actual issue was I was running the application with vpn on, so https request was rejected by the vpn. I managed to solve this without vpn.